# how to add menu on wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

when I have add menu on wordpress it has been added but after save the menu it is not save on menu, I don't have any solution please assist me what is the problem there is.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please contact to your hosting provider to change in file php.ini

max_input_vars = 5000

suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000

suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just deactivate your all plugin and then create new menu and add some page after that check on click on save button I hope there is some problem in your plugin

Comment: hello navnit Thanks for reply, when I started to add menu at that times all plugins are avail on my dashboard but at that time it has been added but now it has been create problem. an other solutions you have please suggest me.